# Recommended architecture for a ASP.NET MVC 2/3 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a ASP.NET MVC 2/3 project on Codeplex and alike with a good architecture for a mid-sized web application. Does anyone knows of a good one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Sharp-Architecture](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture) and [The Tekpub ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Starter Site](http://mvcstarter.codeplex.com/).
There is also [MVC Turbine](http://mvcturbine.codeplex.com/) too

Comment: Sharp-Architecture is way over engineered.

Comment: @jfar - I agree that Sharp-Architecture is over engineered to a great degree, at least for medium sized apps.  For large scale apps I think it's just right.

Answer (score 2):

Get a copy of [Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 by Steve Sanderson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865). He provides realistic guidance without over complicating the concept while addressing "the hard" questions.

There is a new edition of his book that targets MVC 3 that you might want to consider instead but I have not read that one yet so I cannot comment on it. I assume it is equally good, though.

Comment: Or, the new MVC 3 version that just came out.  http://www.apress.com/9781430234043

Answer (score 1):

NerdDinner being updated to MVC3 with Razor, HTML5, GeoLocation, EF CodeFirst, jQuery Mobile, YepNope and Modernizr and a fixed Mobile Device Capabilities ViewEngine

Read more at
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NerdDinnerBeingUpdatedToMVC3WithRazorHTML5GeoLocationEFCodeFirstJQueryMobileYepNopeAndModernizrAndAFixedMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Orchard http://orchardproject.net/

Answer (score -1):

[NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) is the canononical example.

Comment: Not really.  NerdDinner is a great example of how to use MVC, but it's a terrible example of how a real application should be built in MVC.  It access data directly from the controller, doesn't bother with any kind IoC or Tiers or any kind.. etc..

Comment: @Mystere Man - You are totally wrong.  Nerd dinner is tiered, accesses data through a repository and has support for adding a DI container of your choice.

Comment: @jfar - from the Nerddinner tutorial page 160 - http://content.wrox.com/wroxfiles/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v2.pdf - "We won’t be using a Dependency Injection/IoC framework with our NerdDinner application. But it is something we could consider for the future if the NerdDinner code-base and capabilities grew."

Comment: @jfar - also, the EF classes are added directly to the models folder of the site.  This is not a tiered app.  In fact, the word "tier" doesn't even exist in the tutorial.  Yes, it does use a repository pattern, but it passes the EF classes directly to the UI via the controller.

Comment: Agree with @Mystere Man. Don't know what your on about @jfar. 1) `Tier != Layer`. Just because it's a seperate project, unless it's deployed to a different server it's not multi-tiered. 2) Passing EF models to the View is a big no-no. For one, you should always use ViewModels. And since your web tier "knows" about the EF objects, it defeats the point of the repository in the first place. You should be passing POCO's from your Repo to your Controller, then mapping to ViewModels before passing onto the View.

Comment: @RPM1984, @Mystere Man - I don't know how to respond.  Certain applications don't need the things you both are talking about.  Nerddinner is IoC ready and nothing is hugely wrong with passing models from ef directly to the view.  It always depends on the context.  Nerddinner is certainly tiered and layered and is perfectly architected for a small to medium size app.  The reason nerddinner is a really good example is because it isn't bogged down by really opinionated design principals which serve little purpose.

Comment: The other examples require you to "buy into" principals which aren't needed for every application and the lack of which isn't going to hurt anything.  Nerdinner is clean and simple.

Comment: @jfar - "The reason nerddinner is a really good example is because it isn't bogged down by really opinionated design principals which serve little purpose", exactly - and it's **your opinion** that it serves no purpose. So there's really no point in discussing this as we're on opposite sides of the fence. I withdraw gracefully.