# ASP.net MVC 3 tutorial recommendation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

What is a good MVC 3 tutorial for beginner/intermediate/Advanced?

Definitive and authoritative sources are preferred.

Either websites or books are fine.

Answer (score 7):

The best ASP.NET MVC tutorial I know is the NerdDinner application contained in "Professional ASP.NET MVC 3". It has been created by Scott Hanselman and is in production use online at http://www.NerdDinner.com.

---

**[Update] An even better tutorial (and one that is more up-to-date) is the official [ASP.NET MVC Music Store Step-by-Step Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1).**

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the NerdDinner application as the best one. It's certainly one to look into but be careful with it. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737739/recommended-architecture-for-a-asp-net-mvc-2-3-web-application/6737762#6737762

Comment: @Hector Thanks. Any good architecture for mvc you would like to recommend.

Comment: @Pingpong: The book Pro ASP.NET Framework MVC3 that stack72 mentioned is very good and explains the philosophy very well and provides a decent code sample. But from your comments on his answer it seems that his book on MVC 2 wasn't your thing so I am not sure the latest edition would be different for you.

Answer (score 7):

[www.pluralsight.com](http://www.pluralsight.com) has fantastic tutorial videos for many of microsoft's technologies.

Answer (score 6):

the [ASP.NET MVC](http://asp.net/mvc) site is a decent tutorial to get started with (MVC Music store) as it shows the basics but I can suggest the following books as well:

- [Professional ASP.NET MVC3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Jon-Galloway/dp/1118076583/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1311668230&sr=8-1)
- [Pro ASP.NET Framework MVC3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-3rd/dp/1430234040/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1311668230&sr=8-2)

I think it's important to point out here that the tutorials are a good starting point - they will not make you an expert. It will be through external reading and practice that MVC will feel "easy" to you. Remember though, there are other books, these are just 2 from the ones I know and have read

Comment: @statck72, between those two books, which one is better. Because the Pro ASP.NET Framework MVC3 does NOT have many good reviews on amazon.com. It said there are too many errors in Pro ASP.NET Framework MVC3. The Professional ASP.NET MVC3 is yet to publish.

Comment: from experience the Pro series is fantastic - I have 1 and 2 that Steven Sanderson wrote. I enjoyed the Professional ASP.NET MVC book (first link) as well - not sure what it will be like compared to the Pro Framework 3 book (second link)

Comment: @Pingpong: I would strongly recommend Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework despite what the reviews in Amazon show. I found this book right on target as it tackles the "difficult" questions without over complicating the things.

Comment: @PingPong as Hector says - the Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework book comes from a great series. Reviews are very subjective so sometimes help to take them with a pinch of salt! :)

Comment: Thanks. but the authors for Professional ASP.NET MVC3 are in the develop team. I tried Pro ASP.NET Framework MVC2, feel wording and example a bit diffuclt to understand, compared to Stephen's MVC. Any more reason to read Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework?

Comment: I own the Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework book and i have to say this is a masterpiece.

Answer (score 3):

i found out the resources on asp.net mvc page very useful(the link is http://www.asp.net/mvc). there are also video tutorials on the home page which cover the basics of mvc.